# link is not working in review of the product in opencart?

Tags: opencart

I am new to opencart and just started to learn it. i want to know that there are two links with every product named 0 reviews and  Write a review in opencart but there is no any link is given by clicking on it. how to do it from admin that user click on it to give review and admin should know that how many reviews are given by user?

Comment: Are You using the default theme or some third-party one?

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to admin panel.
2. Go to `Catalog > Reviews` - All reviews are listed here.
3. Click on edit to Enable/ Disable the review - By default the reviews are disabled.

Have a nice day :) !

Comment: but it is done from admin side. the reviews should be from user side. then how to do it? and write review link is still disabled.

Comment: There might be some js issue. Please check the changes that you've made.

Answer (score 0):

auto enable reviews.
add status = '1'

edit: catalog/model/catalog/review.php

find

```
 public function addReview($product_id, $data) {
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "review SET author = '" . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . "', customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', text = '" . $this->db->escape(strip_tags($data['text'])) . "', rating = '" . (int)$data['rating'] . "', date_added = NOW()");
}
```

change to

```
public function addReview($product_id, $data) {
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "review SET author = '" . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . "', customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', text = '" . $this->db->escape(strip_tags($data['text'])) . "', rating = '" . (int)$data['rating'] . "', status = '1', date_added = NOW()");
}
```

auto enable reviews.